# How to edit additional data in HABTM tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

How do I update additional data in HABTM tables.

For Example: I have `movies`, `people` and HABTM `movies_people` tables, but there is additional `persontype_id` field in `movies_people` table which indicates role of this person in that particular movie. How do I add/change this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using a has_many :through association, which was introduced just for this reason. Instead of just a movies_people table, you'd have an additional model, called somthing like Favorite or Viewing (depending on what you're trying to accomplish with the association), which belongs_to both :movies and :people, and in your Movie model, you'd do

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :people, :through => :favorites
```

This gives you access to movie.people for all the people who have favored this movie and movie.favorites to access anything that would be in your favorites table (like persontype_id)

Josh Susser's Article, [Many-to-Many Dance Off](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off) does a much better job of explaining this that I could ever hope, so for additional help, I'd take a look at it. http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off

Answer (score 2):

There is also a great Railscast on the subject, by Ryan Bates:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many